# Script pdf printing of webpage that has printSelectedDiv javascript using Powershell

Tags: javascript, powershell, internet-explorer, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

In several scripts, I use [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) in Powershell to headless print pdfs of webpage content.  This works well except on websites busy with widgets and javascript complexity where the pdf print output is a jumbled mess.

One such webpage offers a button to print and uses javascript `printSelectedDiv`.  This opens the Windows print dialog and will print exactly the desired div from the complex page.

I am able using Powershell to automate clicking and submitting the printjob.  However, I want in a headless manner to perform this in a scheduled task like several other scripts.

I'm able to automate the printing as follows with Sendkeys:

```
$ie = new-object -ComObject "InternetExplorer.Application"
$requestUri = "https://www.complexpagefullofwidgets.com"
$ie.silent = $true
$ie.navigate($requestUri)
while($ie.Busy) { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100 }
$doc = $ie.Document

$pdfPrinter = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Printer | Where{$_.Name -eq "Microsoft Print to PDF"}
$pdfPrinter.SetDefaultPrinter() | Out-Null

$printButton = $doc.getElementsByTagName("a") | Where-Object {$_.id -eq "btnPrintList"}
$printButton.click()

Start-Sleep -Second 2

$wshell = New-Object -com WScript.Shell
$wshell.sendkeys("{ENTER}")
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
$wshell.sendkeys("%n")
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
$wshell.sendkeys("c:\temp\temp.pdf")
$wshell.sendkeys("{ENTER}")
```

Is there a better scripted control of this process instead of sending keystrokes?  I don't know if sending keystrokes would reliably work headless in a scheduled task if at all.

Comment: What happens when you try to print these pages as they are?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what you are asking - as they are.

Comment: What happens if you print the pages using wkhlmtopdf?

Comment: Yes, the particular website is full of undesirable content and wkhtmltopdf results in a jumbled mess.  The print button javascript of the page launches the Windows print dialog of only the desired print content.  I cannot figure a way to replicate by script except Sendkeys.

Comment: I was hoping wkhtmltopdf could render only a specific div or allow me to select desired css.  I could not find such options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to keep using wkhtmltopdf, you can use this approach.

Your code completely gets the job done, all you need to do is call the `$printButton.click()` method, then check back on `$ie.Document`, the `Body.InnerHTML` object will contain the full HTML of the page you requested, so you could send that over to wkhtmltopdf.

```
$ie.Document.body.innerHTML > c:\temp\Page.html
& 'C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe' c:\temp\page.html c:\temp\page.pdf
```

The only problem is resolving the image URLs, you'd have to replace the urls in the tags, change them from relative links to absolute links, subbing the \ for the full url of the page you're loading.

Comment: The problem I have this morning is: checking back on `$ie.Document`.  It is the same page, not the page opened by the click.  When I resolve being able to capture the page opened by the click, this should be the answer.

Comment: The new tab that opens upon click is an about:blank with print dialog.  [image of link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5_yG_Yd_HXCdEpXcS14RmlhX2M/view?usp=sharing) I cannot find a way to access its document.

Comment: I was looking at the problem too closely.  All I need to do is send the desired div to the temp file and print that.  `$doc.getElementById("divaddetails").InnerHtml > c:\temp\Page.html`

Comment: Good job man, I was having a hard time with the last bit myself.  I think the real credit goes to you.